# Find sum of real roots of the equation $\sqrt{8-x}=x-2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve the equation $\sqrt{8-x}=x-2.$

I got the answer to the question as $x= -1$ or $x= 4$. However, the answer key says the actual answer to the question is $4$ only. What am I missing here?

Comment: You are missing that $\sqrt{9}\neq -3$.

Comment: I get that the question is quite basic but does that warrant downvotes? Genuine question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the fact that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ where | . | refers to the absolute value, we can apply this to your specific problem to see that:

- $\sqrt{9}=\sqrt{3^2}=|3|=3$

or

- $\sqrt{9}=\sqrt{(-3)^2}=|-3|=3$

Therefore, since $\sqrt{9}\neq-3$, we conclude that $x=-1$ cannot be a valid solution, and so the correct answer is only $x=4$, as stated in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

While it is commonplace to solve an equation such as $ \ \sqrt{8 - x} \ = \ x - 2 \ $ by first "squaring" both sides, it should be understood that this has the effect of altering the properties of the functions represented on each side of the equation.  The curve for the function $ \ y \ = \ x - 2 \ $ (blue curve in graph at left) is a straight line which does not enter the second quadrant, so there is no negative value of $ \ x \ $ that can produce a positive value for $ \ y \ \ . $  The curve (in red) for $ \ y \ = \ \sqrt{8 - x} \ \ , $  on the other hand, can *only* produce positive values of $ \ y \ $ for $ \ x \ < \ 8 \ \ , $ as square-roots of positive real numbers are only defined to *be* positive.  So the properties of these functions tell us that there can be **no intersection** of their curves for $ \ x \ < \ 0 \ \ . $

The act of "squaring" the functions (which enables the solution $ \ (x - 2)^2 \ = \ x^2 - 4x + 4 \ = \ 8 - x $ $ \Rightarrow \ x^2 - 3x - 4 \ = \ (x - 4)·(x + 1) \ = \ 0 \ ) \ $ alters ("transforms") the straight line function into an "upward-opening" parabola with its vertex at $ \ (2 \ , \ 0 ) \ $ and its $ \ y-$intercept at $ \ (0 \ , \ 4) \ \ , $ so that its function curve (green in the graph at right) now extends into the second quadrant, permitting it to intersect with the straight line (orange) for $ \ (\sqrt{8 - x})^2 \ \ . $  This intersection at $ \ (-1 \ , \ 9) \ $ is then an artifact ("spurious solution") of the "squaring" transformation: any negative-value solution for $ \ x \ $ is already "rejected" for the original functions.

Answer (score 0):

*To solve you need to square the given equation.
When you square the right side you get same result for x -2 and 2 - x , therefore you get solutions for both cases. This is why you need to avoid squaring of equations when you are solving. But if there is no other option you can square but you have to check validity of your solutions by substituting those to the original equation.*